# Group by + New column + oldest date when type repated

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by, conditional-statements

I have this dataset:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4],
                  'date':['1995-09-01','1995-09-02','1995-10-03','1995-10-04','1995-10-05','1995-11-07','1995-11-08','1995-11-09','1995-11-10','1995-11-15','1995-12-18','1995-12-20'],
                  'type':['a','b','a','x','b','a','x','a','x','b','a','b']})
```

Which gives me this:

```
user    date    type
1   1995-09-01  a
1   1995-09-02  b
2   1995-10-03  a
2   1995-10-04  x
2   1995-10-05  b
3   1995-11-07  a
3   1995-11-08  x
3   1995-11-09  a
3   1995-11-10  x
3   1995-11-15  b
4   1995-12-18  a
4   1995-12-20  b
```

and I want to get a new column, with dates based on **a** values. When a user has more than an value type a value , the date of the **oldest a** value of this user should be selected to show on the new column.

For example, **user 3** has several **a** values on the *type column*. Thus, on the *a_type_date column*, the **eldest date for the a** value is chosen.

Here is the desired output.

```
user    date      type   a_type_date
    1   1995-09-01  a     1995-09-01
    1   1995-09-02  b     1995-09-01
    2   1995-10-03  a     1995-10-03
    2   1995-10-04  x     1995-10-03
    2   1995-10-05  b     1995-10-03
    3   1995-11-07  a     1995-11-07
    3   1995-11-08  x     1995-11-07
    3   1995-11-09  a     1995-11-07
    3   1995-11-10  x     1995-11-07
    3   1995-11-15  b     1995-11-07
    4   1995-12-18  a     1995-12-18
    4   1995-12-20  b     1995-12-18
```

I tried following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870324/groupby-conditional-from-another-column-to-create-new-one), but I would get duplicates.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @serge-ballesta I would appreciate if you could have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following steps:
 1. First, convert the `date` column into a `datetime()` index:
 `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)`
 2. Next use `min()` and list comprehension to create a new column containing your earliest (use `max()` for latest) type a dates per user as follows:
 `df['a_type_date'] = [min(df[(df.user==i)&(df.type=='a')]['date']).date() for i in df.user]`
The above will generate the desired output as stated in your original query.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `merge`

```
df=df.merge(df.loc[df.type.eq('a'), ['user','date']], on = 'user', how = 'left')
```

Comment: thanks. Your code does create duplicates. I only need one date  for the "a" values of each user. When one user has several "a" values, the oldest one should be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
data = {'user': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
        'date': pd.to_datetime(['1995-09-01', '1995-09-02', '1995-10-03', '1995-10-04',
                               '1995-10-05', '1995-11-07', '1995-11-08', '1995-11-09',
                               '1995-11-10', '1995-11-15', '1995-12-18', '1995-12-20']),
        'type': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'x', 'b', 'a', 'x', 'a', 'x', 'b', 'a', 'b']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
"""print(df)
    user       date type
0      1 1995-09-01    a
1      1 1995-09-02    b
2      2 1995-10-03    a
3      2 1995-10-04    x
4      2 1995-10-05    b
5      3 1995-11-07    a
6      3 1995-11-08    x
7      3 1995-11-09    a
8      3 1995-11-10    x
9      3 1995-11-15    b
10     4 1995-12-18    a
11     4 1995-12-20    b
"""


df['lowest_Date_index'] = df.groupby('user')['type'].transform(
    lambda x : x[x == 'a'].idxmin() if len(x[x =='a']) > 0 else None 
    
)

df['lowest_Date_wrt_type_a'] = df['lowest_Date_index'].apply(
    lambda x : df['date'].loc[x] if pd.notna(x) else None 
    )

print(df.to_string())
"""
   user       date type  lowest_Date_index lowest_Date_wrt_type_a
0      1 1995-09-01    a                  0             1995-09-01
1      1 1995-09-02    b                  0             1995-09-01
2      2 1995-10-03    a                  2             1995-10-03
3      2 1995-10-04    x                  2             1995-10-03
4      2 1995-10-05    b                  2             1995-10-03
5      3 1995-11-07    a                  5             1995-11-07
6      3 1995-11-08    x                  5             1995-11-07
7      3 1995-11-09    a                  5             1995-11-07
8      3 1995-11-10    x                  5             1995-11-07
9      3 1995-11-15    b                  5             1995-11-07
10     4 1995-12-18    a                 10             1995-12-18
11     4 1995-12-20    b                 10             1995-12-18
"""
```

If we don't want to min date wrt to type a, then :

```
df['lowest_Date_index'] = df.groupby('user')['date'].transform(
    lambda x : x.idxmin() if len(x) > 0 else None 
    
)

df['lowest_Date'] = df['lowest_Date_index'].apply(
    lambda x : df['date'].loc[x] if pd.notna(x) else None 
    )
""" 
      user  date      lowest_Date_index lowest_Date
0      1 1995-09-01                  0  1995-09-01
1      1 1995-09-02                  0  1995-09-01
2      2 1995-10-03                  2  1995-10-03
3      2 1995-10-04                  2  1995-10-03
4      2 1995-10-05                  2  1995-10-03
5      3 1995-11-07                  5  1995-11-07
6      3 1995-11-08                  5  1995-11-07
7      3 1995-11-09                  5  1995-11-07
8      3 1995-11-10                  5  1995-11-07
9      3 1995-11-15                  5  1995-11-07
10     4 1995-12-18                 10  1995-12-18
11     4 1995-12-20                 10  1995-12-18
"""
```